# How to flash the firmware of an Intel onboard ethernet adapter

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, firmware, efi, device-manager

**Situation**

I want to update/flash the firmware of my onboard ethernet adapter (Intel I218-V on an ASUS Maximus Ranger VII board). Intel has a tool `bootutil` that can be used for this purpose, but the documentation is very sparse.

**Question**

How do I update/flash the firmware of my onboard LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel does not provide support for OEM products. The tool `bootutil` might theoretically flash on-board adapters as well, but its not supported and OEM's might have used customized firmware. They told me to ask ASUS for firmware. ASUS reported to me that they do not supply firmware.

The answer seems to be: you can only flash corrupted firmware of on-board ethernet adapters if your OEM supplies specific tools for this. This was not the case for the Intel I218-V on an ASUS Maximus Ranger VII board.